# Tag modification: "Muslim-empire" to something more specfic

Tags: discussion, tags

[This recent question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/1859/742) has created the tag, "muslim-empire".  This is a rather vague reference, just as "chirstian-empire" could refer to the Franks, the Byzantines, the Russians, the Spanish, etc.  I think what the author of the tag was referencing was the early Islamic caliphates.  I think it would be far more clear if we divided this tag into its respective caliphates: the [Rashidun-Caliphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashidun), [Umayyad-Caliphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umayyad_Caliphate), and the [Abassid-Caliphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abassid).

Comment: I think its been said before but its a Community site so if you feel that the tags need to be changed make the change.  Personally I am in agreement with you, vague and amorphous terms like that do little to further the questions.  It's a good idea and a good change

Comment: @MichaelF I understand that this is a community site, which is why I went ahead and made the change.  I just posted this to provide an explanation for the change on record and to solicit discussion on the matter.  I think most people here would agree the original tag was too vague, but I think there is plenty of potential for divergence in what to change the tag to.  I think that's a good reason for posting on an SE meta site, right?

Comment: Sure, the Meta site needs love too.  I'm in agreement but when I can I just try to mention this is a Community Site, it's nothing to do with you.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I see you went ahead and did it. I approve. "Muslim Empire" doesn't really make any more sense than "Christian Empire" would.

I suppose I could see just one for "Caliphate". That would at least strongly imply the period where there was only one Caliph, rather than perhaps encompassing the Mughal Empire in India, like "muslim-empire" might.

Answer (score 2):

My only concern with the changes that BrotherJack made to the tag, or rather the tags he added, is that it runs the risk of overspecializing tags. I think "caliphate" may have been a more appropriate choice since it would be a little more encompassing.

Comment: That was the only thing I worried about.  I also thought about using just "caliphate", but there were many "caliphates" especially near the end of the Umayyad caliphate and the Abassid caliphate.  In the post the author is obviously referring to the line of caliphs initiated from the succession of Abu Bakr.  My feeling is that if the tags are not utilized in 6 months they'll die a natural death.

Comment: I thought the tags, as long as they are associated with one question, will stay forever.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest.  I remember reading if the tags aren't used in a half-year period they're dropped.  I don't think its too big of a deal, since it is virtually equivalent to say a "Romanov" tag, and I certainly argue the importance of such a tag even if it is associated with a limited number of posts.